Getting error 500 on DELETE request in Postman
I am following a node.js & express api tutorial to build an expense tracker. I am making get, post and delete requests on postman. The GET and POST request are working fine but i get status as 500 when i make a DELETE request. Consider the following:
POST:
http://localhost:5000/api/v1/transactions
Output:
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "text": "Payment",
        "amount": -100,
        "_id": "6662fcccc69f5411146a4205",
        "createdAt": "2024-06-07T12:27:56.355Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
}

GET:
http://localhost:5000/api/v1/transactions
Output:
{
    "success": true,
    "count": 3,
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "6662f5b0432dc072d8281525",
            "text": "Bonus",
            "amount": 50,
            "createdAt": "2024-06-07T11:57:36.455Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "6662f654432dc072d8281528",
            "text": "Books",
            "amount": 150,
            "createdAt": "2024-06-07T12:00:20.681Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "6662fcccc69f5411146a4205",
            "text": "Payment",
            "amount": -100,
            "createdAt": "2024-06-07T12:27:56.355Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}

Note: I earlier added **Bonus** and **Books**
DELETE: say i want to delete 'Payment', so i get its _id and do:
http://localhost:5000/api/v1/transactions/6662fcccc69f5411146a4205
Output:
{
    "success": false,
    "error": "Server Error"
}

The controllers file (transactions.js) is as follows:
const Transaction = require('../models/Transaction');

// @desc    Get all transactions
// @route   GET /api/vi/transactions 
// @access  Public
exports.getTransactions = async (req, res, next) => {
    // res.send('GET transactions');
    try {
        const transactions = await Transaction.find();

        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            count: transactions.length,
            data: transactions
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            error: 'Server Error'
        });
    }
}


// @desc    Add transaction
// @route   POST /api/vi/transactions 
// @access  Public
exports.addTransaction = async (req, res, next) => {
    // res.send('POST transaction');

    try {
        const { text, amount } = req.body;

        const transaction = await Transaction.create(req.body);
    
        return res.status(201).json({
            success: true,
            data: transaction
        });
        
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.name === 'ValidationError') {
            const messages = Object.values(err.errors).map(val => val.message);

            return res.status(400).json({
                success: false,
                error: messages
            });
        } else {
            return res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                error: 'Server Error'
            });
        }
    }
}


// @desc    Delete transaction
// @route   DELETE /api/vi/transactions/:id
// @access  Public
exports.deleteTransaction = async (req, res, next) => {
    // res.send('DELETE transaction');
    try {
        const transaction = await Transaction.findById(req.params.id);

        if(!transaction) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                success: false,
                error: 'No transaction found'
            });
        }

        await transaction.remove(); //remove method is called on the resource

        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            data: {}
        });

    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            error: 'Server Error'
        });
    }
}

Please somebody help. How do i solve this?


You find out what the server error is 2. You investigate why the error would show up 3. You correct the reason for there to be an error. That's the only common way to fix 500 errors. Because it means nothing more than "something on the server didn't work". There is no common way to address it other than starting out with what the problem was.


It looks like you are using mongoose and are trying to to use remove() in the delete route handler. This was deprecated in V7. You should use one of the alternatives suggested. Also you should console.log(err) in the catch block so you can actually see for yourself what errors you are catching. I would personally just use const transaction= await Transaction.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id). If it's null it means nothing was found otherwise it was deleted.

@jQueeny i did console.log(err) and i got TypeError: transaction.remove is not a function. Hence as you suggested, i used findByIdAndDelete and it worked! I commented out the await transaction.remove() and it is working. Thankyou very much:)

It's good practice to send a generic 500 message to your front-end like you've done but as you've realised, logging the error on the server allows you to check the logs and debug. Mongoose migration docs do a good job at outlining deprecated methods so always consult them in the first instance. Glad you got it working.

Upon doing console.log(err), I got TypeError: transaction.remove is not a function, i.e., it is deprecated.
Instead, I used const transaction = await Transaction.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id) which solved the problem.
findByIdAndDelete finds and deletes the document, returning the deleted document.
It returns the document that was deleted, or null if no document with the given _id exists.
I commented out the await transaction.remove() because findByIdAndDelete does the job.
There's an another way this can be solved:
Keep findById unchanged, just do await transaction.deleteOne(). This also does the job.
Anyway, this problem has been resolved. Thanks to @jQueeny!
